# How do I set an array equal to all these inputs?

Tags: java

This program allows the user to create multiple clients. How do I allow an array to be equal to all these inputs? When I display the array the only thing that is shown is the last client added.

```
static String [] clients = new String[100];

void getClient()
    {
        String input = new String (" ");
        for(int i = 0; i < ccount; i++)
            clients[i] = input;
        {
        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter client ID: ");
            while(checkClientID(input) == false)
            {   
                input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Invalid! Only 9 digits allowed. Re-enter client ID: ");
            }//end while
        clientID = input;
        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter client name: ");
            while(checkCname(input) == false)
            {   
                input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Invalid! Only 50 alphabetical characters allowed! Re-enter client name: ");
            }//end while
        cname = input;
        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter client address: ");
        caddress = input;
        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter client email: ");
            while(checkCemail(input) == false)
            {   
                input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Invalid! Must enter at least  one character before @ and .com at end, Re-enter email: ");
            }//end while 
        cemail = input;
        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter monthly service fees: ");
            while(checkCfees(input) == false)
            {   
                input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Invalid! Must enter real number with two decimal places, Re-enter monthly service fees: ");
            }//end while
        cfees = input;
        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Employee ID assigned to client: ");
        while(checkEmpID(input) == false)
        {   
            input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Invalid! Only 9 digits allowed. Re-enter employee ID: ");
        }//end while
        cempID = input;
        mainMenu();
        }//end for 
    }//end getClient
```

Comment: I edited to where I added the array.

Comment: I don't understand the problem.
Did you try `array[index] = information`?

Comment: The way you added it in the code snippet does not work, because (1) it needs to be inside the braces, and too, the assignment needs to be at the end of the loop, after the input has been obtained, not in the beginning:   `for { ... clients[i] = input; }`

Comment: so add clients[i] after each input or just at the very end once?

Answer (score 0):

Using ArrayList:

First, declare an ArrayList of ArrayList:

```
static ArrayList<ArrayList> clients = new ArrayList<>();
```

Each time the function `getCliente()` is called a Customer is added to the list:

```
public static void getCliente() {                
    String input;                
    clients.add(new ArrayList<>());
    int i=clients.size()-1;

    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter client ID: ");
        while(checkClientID(input) == false)
        {   
            input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Invalid! Only 9 digits allowed. Re-enter client ID: ");
        }//end while
    clientID = input;
    clients.get(i).add(clientID);
    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter client name: ");
        while(checkCname(input) == false)
        {   
            input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Invalid! Only 50 alphabetical characters allowed! Re-enter client name: ");
        }//end while
    cname = input;
    clients.get(i).add(cname);
    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter client address: ");
    caddress = input;
    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter client email: ");
        while(checkCemail(input) == false)
        {   
            input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Invalid! Must enter at least  one character before @ and .com at end, Re-enter email: ");
        }//end while 
    cemail = input;
    clients.get(i).add(cemail);
    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter monthly service fees: ");
        while(checkCfees(input) == false)
        {   
            input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Invalid! Must enter real number with two decimal places, Re-enter monthly service fees: ");
        }//end while
    cfees = Double.parseDouble(input);
    clients.get(i).add(cfees);
    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Employee ID assigned to client: ");
    while(checkEmpID(input) == false)
    {   
        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Invalid! Only 9 digits allowed. Re-enter employee ID: ");
    }//end while
    cempID = input;
    clients.get(i).add(cempID);
    //mainMenu();      
}
```

To iterating, and print the list we use this function:

```
public static void printClients() {
    for (ArrayList client: clients) {
        System.out.println("Client ID: " + client.get(0));
        System.out.println("Client name: " + client.get(1));
        System.out.println("Client address: " + client.get(2));
        System.out.println("Client email: " + client.get(3));
        System.out.println("Monthly service fees: " + client.get(4));
        System.out.println("Employee ID assigned to client: " + client.get(5));
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------");
    }
}
```